# Growth Rate Problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I want a number `x` to grow to the number `y` over `z` periods, how do I compute my growth rate per period? So assume `x` = 10, and `y` = 80 and `z` = 3, then I would have a growth rate of 100% every period:

- 10
- 20 (1st period)
- 40 (2nd period)
- 80 (3rd period)

How to compute that growth rate?

Comment: That's really 3 periods, not 4. Classic [fence post error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fence_post_error).

Comment: Ah, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to think of growth factor at first: So your number is multiplied by $g$ at each step. After $z$ steps, it is multiplied by $g^z$, so you end up with an equation $$g^zx=y$$ to be solved for $g$. To do that, take logarithms and end up with a linear equation for $\log g$.

Afterwards, you convert your $g$ to a growth rate $g-1$. Multiply by 100 if you want it as a percentage.

In your example, the equation is $$g^3\cdot10=80,$$ i.e., $g^3=8$. You hardly need logs to do that one, but if you do, logarithms with base 2 can't be beat: $3\log_2 g=\log_28=3$, so $\log_2g=1$, and $g=2^1=2$.

Comment: can you rewrite the formula with `g` on the left side and `x`, `y`, and `z` on the right side? I'm trying to put this formula in GDocs Spreadsheet and need something simple.

Comment: $g=(\frac{y}{x})^{\frac{1}{z}}$

Comment: @Avatar: Indeed. I was just typing it up myself, but you beat me to it by a few seconds. I could well have done the whole thing without the logs, but I was in a hurry when typing my answer and the obvious solution didn't occur to me (duh).

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I wrote the formula correct, but the approach to solve is exactly you gave in your answer. Here, taking $z^{th}$ root was simple, but in general first you have to first compute $\log g$ using $\log$ tables and then compute $anti-log$ of $\log g$ to get $g$